# Circular relationship in UML Diagram Class

Tags: loops, class, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I have a problem in my diagram class.
here is the logic :

- user can create a campaign
- user can make donation ( transaction in the image ) to a campaign
- user have a lis of donations to different campaigns
- campaign have a list of donations from different users

the problem : since its not recommended , i want to avoid the circular relationship but i don't know how ?
any help ?

[image]

Comment: Could you clarify why you think that a circular or a triangular relationship is not recommended?

Answer (score 0):

This is not a circular relationship. What you see is a simple Association (as you mentioned for noting the creation) and the other is an Association Class. This is used to note the Transactions between `User` and `Compaign` (guess that's a typo here).